# Removing an item from the dictionary provided that the key numbers are still consecutive

Tags: python, dictionary

**students = {1 : "Lucas" , 2 : "Rose" , 3 : "Jack"}**
This is my student's dictionary and I want to delete an item in the event that the keys still consecutive.

*for example :*
if I deleted **Rose**:
students = {1 : "Lucas" , 2 : "Jack"}
*(Jack key changed)*

The key that deleted in the dictionary must be determined by the user.

Comment: Why aren't you using a list in the first place?

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/

Comment: Because in the project, we need to have a dictionary of students

Comment: Just make a loop from the index you are deleting to the last one and update that dictionary value with the next one. Something like `for i in range(idx, n-1): myDict[i] = myDict[i+1]`

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki one has to remember to delete `i+1`th element afterwards though.

Comment: The I+1 element will be overwritten in the next iteration. Yes you need to handle the special case of the very last element, but this is something the OP will have to realize by him/herself

Comment: It might be more efficient to use a list, and when you "need to have" this dict just recompute it with dict(enumerate(students, start=1))

Comment: Just to clarify the question, the numbers are "keys", and the names are "values." You say delete by key, but the example is a delete by value.

Comment: In your example, does the user provide the key 2 or the value 'Rose'? What would happen if keys 8 & 9 (for example) each had the same value? Have you really thought about this?

Comment: the key  . The values of  dictionary are already entered manually and none of them are equal.

Answer (score 0):

You can delete the key (ensuring that it actually exists) then rebuild the dictionary as follows:

```
students = {1: "Lucas", 2: "Rose", 3: "Jack"}

def delete_by_key(_dict, key):
    try:
        del _dict[key]
    except KeyError:
        pass
    return dict(zip(range(1, len(_dict)+1), _dict.values()))

students = delete_by_key(students, 2)

print(students)
```

**Output:**

```
{1: 'Lucas', 2: 'Jack'}
```